# Getting text of node and children excluding one

Tags: python, xpath

What I want to do is taking all text from a node and it's children but excluding one of the child.

So here's the HTML with it:

```
<blocquote>
  <div class='quote'>
    I don't want to get that.
  </div>

Some text I want to <i> get </i>.

  <div>
    I want to get this.
  </div>
</blockquote>
```

I already tried:

`xpath("//blocquote/text()")`
but it will only take `Some text I want to`

`xpath("//blocquote//text()`
but it will take everything including `I don't want to get that`

`xpath("//blocquote/*[not(div[@class='quote'])]/text()`
but it will not take `Some text I want to`

I really don't know if there is a solution for that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could exclude that parent with e.g. `//blocquote//text()[not(parent::div[@class = 'quote'])]`.

Comment: Actially, it's just getting me everything juste like `xpath("//blocquote//text()`

Comment: Oh my bad, it's working!
Only one problem though, it's just not getting the `<i> get </i>`. Any idea why ?

Comment: It looks like it's just excluding ALL children nodes btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use descendant-or-self axis:

```
//blocquote/descendant-or-self::*[not(@class='quote')]/text()
```

Comment: Just as last answer, it's giving me everything.. :(

Comment: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=<blocquote><div class='quote'>I don't want to get that.</div>Some text I want to <i> get </i>.<div>I want to get this.</div></blocquote>&=&extract=%2F%2Fblocquote%2Fdescendant-or-self%3A%3A*%5Bnot(%40class%3D%27quote%27)%5D%2Ftext()&=%2F%2Fblocquote%2Fdescendant-or-self%3A%3A*%5Bnot(%40class%3D%27quote%27)%5D%2Ftext()&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto